# How to make a div to be a custom mouse cursor being able to select text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4lid.png) what I've just made:

The blue dot you see is a div which I want to be a cursor. Here's some code I have now:

```
function handler(e) {
    var coords = getCoords(document.getElementById("cursor"));

    var pageY = coords.top;
    var pageX = coords.left;

    var element = document.elementFromPoint(pageX - 1, pageY - 1);
}
```

This code finds a node which is under that blue dot coordinates and works great (at least for now). That blue dot has the id "cursor".
The thing I actually want to do now is to be able to select text which is under that cursor. I've got this:

```
<span>Text sample sample sample text</span>
```

How can I select a part of this text [from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLajg.png) to [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAUZw.png)? (as an example). Just to select a part of this text (which is in a span element) with moving that cursor through the text selecting it at once as I would do with my mouse? I need to get a character which is under that blue dot? But how?

Is it possible? I know that I can actually select a whole span element using document.createRange, but the point is that I want to select only a part, and this part to be calculated based on the coordinates of the cursor (blue dot). Maybe, if it's not, there's some other ways to do that?

Comment: If I understand you right, then you need to use the CSS property "pointer-events" with the value of "none" on your custom cursor element, this will make it to not interrupt the mouse events.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: I want to select a part of the text with this custom mouse cursor whilemoving it via js.That property you mentioned may be useful for that but I ain't sure it solves my problem. There's an online course called 'Scrimba', and they have this custom cursor that just recorded or something and do these things like selecting text, placing text pointers, and etc. and I want to do the same thing.